# Ajax login doesn't login when using the correct login user data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli, authentication

Hello I am totally new into Ajax. I have made a login with Ajax, but whenever I try to login, I get a message that the login didn't worked. I am looking for hours for the problem but can't find where I got wrong.

This is the body of the **index.html**

```
<div class="loginform-in">
<h1>User Login</h1>
<div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
<fieldset>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li> <label for="name">Username </label>
        <input type="text" size="30"  name="name" id="name"  /></li>
        <li> <label for="name">Password</label>w
        <input type="password" size="30"  name="word" id="word"  /></li>
        <li> <label></label>
        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login" class="loginbutton" ></li>
    </ul>
     </form>    
</fieldset>
</div>
```

I didn't include the ajax code in another file. I did the code below in the head of the **index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'none', 'important');
        $("#login").click(function(){   
            username=$("#name").val();
            password=$("#word").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
                success: function(html){    
                    if(html=='true')    {
         //$("#add_err").html("right username or password");
         window.location="dashboard.php";
        }
        else    {
            $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
            $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or password");
        }
    },
    beforeSend:function()
    {
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
        $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
    }
});
            return false;
        });
    });
```

And this is the **login.php**

```
require_once '../config.php';

session_start();
$uName = $_POST['name'];
$pWord = md5($_POST['pwd']);
$qry = "SELECT usrid, username, oauth FROM ajax WHERE username='".$uName."' AND pass='".$pWord."' AND status='active'";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $qry);
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($res);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if( $num_row == 1 ) {
  echo 'true';
  $_SESSION['uName'] = $row['username'];
  $_SESSION['oId'] = $row['orgid'];
  $_SESSION['auth'] = $row['oauth'];
}
else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: You should use parameterized queries and update your hashing.

Comment: Maybe this condition is never true `if( $num_row == 1 ) {`  try change it to `if( $num_row > 0) {`

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: I can see an error here `$("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile tried changing to if( $num_row > 0), but also didn't logged in. This is the URL: 77331.ict-lab.nl/login

Comment: @BerkBalik and one thing for use you are suppose to get notice of undefined index `orgid`. error reporting is important...  please check my answer below

Comment: this is undifined `$row['orgid'];` therefore its gonna make ur ajax fail

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data: {name:username, pwd:password},
            success: function(html){    
                if(html=='true')    {
     //$("#add_err").html("right username or password");
     window.location="dashboard.php";
    }
    else    {
        $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
        $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/alert.png' />Wrong username or password");
    }
},
beforeSend:function()
{
    $("#add_err").css('display', 'inline', 'important');
    $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...")
}
});
```

Change data

Comment: Answers should have an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to introduce you to the wonderful world of prepared statements using mysqli and pdo and also `password_hash();` and `password_verify()` these will be answers to all your future problems, as @Chris85 have suggested. and since you are using the script on a live server u really need to use prepared statements.

**First method PDO**

```
<div class="loginform-in">
<h1>User Login</h1>
<div class="err" id="add_err"></div>
<fieldset>
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
    <ul>
        <li> <label for="name">Username </label>
        <input type="text" size="30"  name="name" id="name"  /></li>
        <li> <label for="name">Password</label>w
        <input type="password" size="30"  name="word" id="word"  /></li>
        <li> <label></label>
        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" value="Login" class="loginbutton" ></li>
    </ul>
     </form>    
</fieldset>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){

        $('#myform').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = $('#myform').serialize();

            $.ajax({

                type : 'post',
                url  :'login.php',
                data : formData,
                dataType : 'json',
                encode : true,
                beforeSend : function(){
                    $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /> Loading...");
                },
                success : function(result){

                    result = JSON.parse(result);

                    if(result == "ok"){

                         $("#add_err").html("right username or password");
                         setTimeout(' window.location.href = "dashboard.php"; ', 6000);
                    }else{

                        $("#add_err").html("<img src='images/alert.png' /> Wrong username or password");
                    }
                }


            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php

    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db   = 'YOURDATABASE';
    $user = 'DBUSER';
    $pass = 'YOURPASSWORD';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            ];

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

?>
```

then **login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

require 'config.php';


$message = '';
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['word'];

    try {

        $stmt    = $dbh->prepare("SELECT usrid,orgid, username,pass,oauth FROM ajax WHERE username= ? AND status='active'");
        $stmt->execute([$username]);
        $results = $stmt->fetchall();

        if (count($results) > 0) {
            //username is correct
            foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
                //verify password
                if (password_verify($password, $row['pass'])) {
                    // password and username correct
                    $_SESSION['uName'] = $row['username'];
                    $_SESSION['oId']   = $row['orgid'];
                    $_SESSION['auth']  = $row['oauth'];
                    $message           = 'ok';
                } else {
                    //username and password does not match

                    $message = 'username and password does not match';
                }
            }
        } else {
            //username is incorrect
            $message = 'incorrect user account';
        }

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {

        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }

    echo json_encode($message);
}

?>
```

That's how simple is it is,  so also on your registration page you will use prepared statements, read here how to insert data with prepared statements : https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dml

> also on the register page you no longer gonna use md5
>
> so instead of `$password = md5($_POST['word']);` you will say
>   `$password = $_post['word'];` then u need to hash that password this
>   is how u will do it `$hash=
>   password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` OR
>   '$hash=password_hash($_POST['word'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Before you can use this you need to make sure that you re register you account using `password_hash();`

**2nd method mysqli prepared** I'm not quit good with this one, i'm more comfortable with PDO, I might make mistakes somewhere, corrections a welcome as i'm also here to learn.

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
$message = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['word'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT usrid, username,pass,orgid,oauth FROM ajax WHERE username= ? AND status='active'");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username,$pass,$orgid,$oauth);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) //username correct
        {
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            if (passord_verify($password, $pass)) {
                // correct username
                $_SESSION['uName'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['oId']   = $orgid
                $_SESSION['auth']  = $oauth;
                $message           = 'ok';

            } else {

                $message = 'username and password does not match';
            }
        }

    } else {
        //username incorrect.
        $message = 'incorrect user account';
    }

    echo json_encode($message);
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
}
```

on the second method use the current config that u have already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer on my question @Masivuye Cokile. I will definitely check PDO. I tried the PDO method, but when I try the code it gets stuck at the loading text...

Comment: comment out this line `result = JSON.parse(result);`  then run again also check what does the console say. add `console.log(result);` @BerkBalik

Comment: No result.. I think it doesn't even reaches the PHP file, because it's stuck on beforeSend and not on success. When logging in it only gives me the "loading..." result. So result = JSON.parse(result); will not be runned.

Comment: there's an error on your php script, please check error log

Comment: You not printing anything in the console add this `console.log(result)`; before `if(result=="ok")`; and also enable error reporting